# Why is my bootable Ubuntu USB not detected on Windows?

Tags: windows, boot

I want to install Ubuntu on my laptop. I entered BIOS(image below)
[image]

Why I can not change boot OPTIONS? My laptop is HP EliteBook 8560.

System Summary shows

[image]

Comment: What is the `Legacy Boot Order`?

Comment: @Randomhero I do not know,I can not move the arrow below. How to fix this?

Comment: @Randomhero Please,take a look now.

Comment: Can you use the mouse to move the scrollbar down and take a screenshot of that?

Comment: @LPChip I can not move it,do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

Partition mismatch could be one of the reason for usb not detected. You should try changing from legacy to uefi and check if the problem exist? In case you cant change the boot option, that may be because your secure boot is enabled. You first have to disable secure boot,you can enable that later after you change from legacy to uefi.
This link down might help you guide to fix your issue:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCxoOyUQqUE

Answer (score 0):

@MikiBelavista have you tried disabling secure boot ? see the steps here (title says about CD/ DVD but it applies to USB too)

https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03736054